# Why can't my sprite won't stop moving? Even if i stop pushing buttons the sprite is still moving

Tags: python, pygame

After hitting a and d or left and right key , the sprite will still move without me pressing the key.He just won't stop.How can i fix this?

```
 def control(self, x, y):
    '''
    control player movement
    '''
    self.movex += x
    self.movey += y


if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
        player.control(-steps , 0)
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
        player.control(steps , 0)



if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
        player.control(0 , 0)
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
        player.control(0 , 0)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You probably just have to change `self.movex += x` to `self.movex = x` (and the same for `self.movey`), but I can't say that certainly without seeing the complete code.